# Tortoise CVS Source Safe

Tags: open-source, tortoisecvs, sourcesafe-6.0

I am very new to Tortoise CVS Source Safe !!

I am working on VS 2008 / SQL Application. I have work from home option and so i decided to upload my source code to the server either from my home or at work.

1) http://www.tortoisecvs.org/download.shtml   :- From this website, which file i need to download and install for setting up the Source Safe.

2) Which will act as Server and Client ??

3) On installing on Server : Do i need to set Port Forwarding for the Server Machine by providing Static IP?

Any document materials, i need to review on using the Online Source Safe Repository. Can i upload Excel / Document Files other than C# files ?

Comment: I'm confused. SourceSafe is a (commercial) product from Microsoft while CVS is an open source versioning tool. What exactly should CVS SourceSafe be?

Comment: a) I am looking for Opensource Source Safe    b) I decided to go for Tortoise CVS as it is Open Source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well Chok, i think what you have installed is the client. CVS server needs to be installed separately. You may download from [CVSNT](http://www.cvsnt.org)